# An Eleven Letter Word

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

A single one, just to heat things up a bit:

> 1-2-3 is a tree I'd much prefer (to vulgar ash)
>
> 4 is actually fifth in line, the second of its kind, for me (but sixth for Cyril)
>
> 5-6-7 is 1-2-3's eastern cousin, but not as big (and much more tasty)
>
> 8-9 is trust in hospitality (stock up on it)
>
> 10-11, I'm unsure (of what to say)

If no-one gets it by tomorrow I'll drop another hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 11 letter word, 'just to heat things up', is

> FIREFIGHTER

a tree I'd much prefer

> FIR tree

actually fifth in line, the second of its kind, for me (but sixth for Cyril)

> E is 5th in the latin alphabet (and 2nd vowel), 6th in cyrillic [абвгде]

eastern cousin, but not as big (and much more tasty)

> FIG tree, yum!

trust in hospitality (stock up on it)

> HT ... well I just inferred it from the other clues. FIREFIG--ER. What else could the two letters be? But as to how the clue fits, I don't know. Stealing hand towels from hotels? [EDIT: using OP's hint: the *stock* symbol for *Hospitality Trust*.]

I'm unsure (of what to say)

> "ER...."

Comment: oh you got me by 30s!

Comment: Brutally quick, nice job! Look up "ht stock" and you'll figure it out. Since this is the first right answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6):

The word is:

> FIREFIGHTER

*1-2-3 is a tree I'd much prefer (to vulgar ash)*

> FIR is type of tree

*4 is actually fifth in line, the second of its kind, for me (but sixth for Cyril)*

> 'E' is the fifth letter of the alphabet (i.e. "fifth in line") and the second vowel. Didn't quite get the Cyril reference (except that the name contains a 'y'?)

*5-6-7 is 1-2-3's eastern cousin, but not as big (and much more tasty)*

> FIG is a type of fruit

*8-9 is trust in hospitality (stock up on it)*

> HT seems to stand for "Hospitality Training" (according to the almighty Google)

*10-11, I'm unsure (of what to say)*

> ER is the sound people generally make when they are unsure of what to say

Comment: Slightly slower, but with 8-9 figured out. Wonder who this goes to.

Comment: My intended meaning for 8-9 is a tad more obscure ("stock" was meant to be a hint).